# Memory getting released in iOS simulator but on device (ipad )its not getting released

Tags: ios, iphone, memory-management, ios7, memory-leaks

Whenever I test the App on simulator the memory rises to 400mb but after sometimes it get released as desired (i.e memory allocated reach 20mb). But when testing the same code on iPad it just release only 50mb  (i.e memory allocated reach to 350mb). Any idea why is this difference in memory deallocation in simulator and device ?

**NB** I am using xcode 5.0 (5A1413) and app was targeted for iOS 7

Comment: Try to make your question more concrete.

Comment: @geminiCoder yes I am using ARC,

Comment: @KudoCC I just wanted to know if memory is getting properly deallocated on simulator and not on my device, is there some issue with my coding ?

Comment: I advise to use "profile" in Xcode to watch the memory of your app.

Comment: @KudoCC yes it tried using "profile" but situation is same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the fact that the simulator is not an **emulator**.

The simulator, does not model iPad/iPhone/iOS behaviour, it simply simulates execution of iOS applications, moreover you should certainly not expect the simulators memory management to represent what you will see on the device.

The simulator gets as much RAM as your Mac can give it.

Comment: ok, so does the dealloc/ object releasing mechanism also varies between iOS simulator and iOS Devices ?

Comment: Yes, potentially, when you call dealloc on the simulator, it may not physically free the memory using the same paradigm iOS does - If my answer has solved your question, please mark as answered.

Comment: So does that mean i have to change the way i dealloc the objects, even though it properly releases in simulator ?

Comment: @rhlnair, no you shouldn't write code that's best for the simulator, but instead best for the device. Test on your target device. You are using ARC, therefore you won't have to manually release your objects. Retain/release calls will be automatically inserted in your code transparently. Are you speaking about tidying up objects to react to say a low memory warning?